# Segue sends a nil value before I can calculate it?

Tags: ios, swift2, segue

I've set a `var message:String=""` as a `global variable` , in a function I calculate its value which I have to send to another `ViewController` through `prepareForSegue`, however it ends up sending the `nil` value,any idea how I can send the latest value through segue? Thanks global variable:
`var message2="bob"`

prepare for segue method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "submitSegue") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! Otpscreen;
        svc.otpname = username.text!
        svc.otppass = password.text!
        svc.otp=message2
    }
}
```

other method where I'm calculating the value:

```
func findMatch()->Void
{
print(username.text!+password.text!)
let authenticate=username.text!+password.text!
//line where i calculated hash
print(hash)
let num=strtoul(hash,nil,16)
print(num)
let finalhash=String(num)
let soap = SOAPEngine()

soap.responseHeader = true;
soap.setValue(username.text!, forKey: "userName")
soap.setValue(password.text!, forKey: "password")
soap.setValue(finalhash, forKey: "hashKey")
let dict:Dictionary = try! soap.syncRequestURL("someUrl", soapAction: "send method ") as Dictionary
NSLog("%@", dict);
let returnmessage=(dict["Body"]!["sendOTPResponse"]!!["sendOTPReturn"]!!["string"]!![1])
print(returnmessage)
message2=returnmessage as! String


}
```

Comment: Please show some code and screen of your storyboard.

Comment: First, you shouldn't use a global variable. Second are you trying to access the value in `viewDidLoad`?  Third, show the code for `prepareForSegue` and where you are accessing the message in the destination view controller

Comment: Im trying to edit my post, theres some issue in attaching the code, meanwhile this is the prepare for segue code:  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "submitSegue") {
            let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! Otpscreen;
            svc.otpname = username.text!
            svc.otppass = password.text!
            svc.otp=message2
        }
    }

Comment: In story board is your segue is created with button action?

Comment: For button I've directly dragged it on to the second screen and then used the show method in its options, so basically if i click the button it will navigate to another screen

Comment: The SOAP request in `findMatch` will complete asynchronously. You will need to trigger the segue programatically from the completion handler once you have the result. Don't forget to dispatch this onto the main queue

Comment: Any idea how i will be able to trigger the segue programatically?

Comment: You need to delete the action segue in the storyboard and create a segue from the view controller object in the storyboard. Give the segue an identifier and then you can use `performSegueWithIdentifier`. If you search for that you will find more information on how to do it

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, `performSegueWithIdentifier` helped, I used it right after my value Changed.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong in the code, but the matter is completion block, after completing the  SOAPEngine response, the segue method has to call after the response. So Use the following code

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(<#delayInSeconds#> * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    <#code to be executed after a specified delay#>
```

// call your segue by programmatically
    });

Comment: Thanks I'm using perform segue with Identifier though! Worked the way i wanted